# Apache Cordova on VS output problems

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Hi I'm new to Apache Cordova. I've recently developed a web application that works fine on chrome and devices but when i get Visual Studio Apache Cordova (visual studio 2015) output some CSS files seem to be not loaded completely i mean some parts of CSS are not working as it must. and the second problem is the output is different in different devices on nexus 5 it is 90% OK but in LG L70 or bluestacks less than 30% is OK.
anyone knows the reason and solution?
Thanks

Comment: What is VS? You surely don't mean Visual Studio.

Comment: yeah Visual Studio 2015 (i edited question) ... why do you ask?

Comment: Ah, now I see. Couldn't grab it before the edit.

Comment: @hsbr13 There seems to be a lot going on in your question and there isn't enough detailed information .  Initially this seems like a `HTML+ CSS + JavaScript` issue.

Best way to get real solid solution is to create a repository on GitHub.  

Best practices for debugging on Device in VS2015 + Cordova:
Use Ripple (Debug > Android > Ripple - XXXX) and JavaScript Console to see JavaScript errors.
Use the Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android to debug and view JavaScript errors in output windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without any code it is hard to tell (and your question is very broad!). I also have to bite my tongue in order to not go raging against Cordova (again).

But from my (luckily) poor experience with Cordova you have do deal with different WebViews and their different implementations.
I recommend you to get the Android WebView version of your device and test your app with this in mind. May you find similarities like "Everything goes wrong in WebView versions below 3.2.1" and modify your app accordingly to your findings.

Comment: its not a small part of my project that i can show it to you there are lots of problems. i had test it on chrome (inspect elements) on various sizes it was fine and opened it by mozilla on different gadgets again everything was ok but today i got an apache cordova that everything was messed up and the problem is not even the same as i mentioned different gadgets have different problems.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you don't have any errors in your html / css by using the online validators.

Second, make sure the CSS you are using is available on the version of Chrome / Android that those devices have (www.caniuse.com).  Make sure you are using the browser specific prefixes where needed (i.e new versions of Chrome would not need, but older Chrome/Webview would).

In my experience that will find many of the issues with a Cordova app, especially on Android.  Most likely your CSS is not taking into consideration all the variation among mobile browsers.  It is not easy to do unless you have done it before.

Another way to ease these issues on Android is to use the Crosswalk plugin.  Since you are using VS 2015 it is real easy and available in the config.xml editor to add.  This will increase build time / size of the app, but it is just about necessary for serious Android hybrid app development.  What crosswalk does is package a new up to date version of Chromium with your app.  It makes many issues like you are seeing go away, plus it gives you a lot of newer web APIs (webrtc for example) on the devices.

One last option is to use a tested / supported library like ionic (can just use their CSS if you want and not full stack), jQuery mobile, Onseen UI, etc...  You can use this together with Crosswalk to get a very consistent experience on all the Android devices / versions.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer I'll try it.One more question: is there any special work i should do to get the same result on different gadgets? as i mentioned right now it is not the same so i should test it on ALL android devices that is not logical. thanks a lot.   And i forgot to say im using JQueryMobile it works fine but my own external CSS is not working.

Comment: You can use the GenyMotion emulator to test on the different versions of Android without having the devices.

If you are using Android 4.4 or later debug the app in VS 2015 when it is running on the device.  You can change your CSS in real time to see what works / doesn't.

On older versions of Android, you can use weinre to do DOM debugging and change the CSS while it is running on the device.